# Does Tdameritrade has Interactive Brokers Python API like IbPy?

Tags: python, stock, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibpy

Does Tdameritrade have Interactive Brokers Python API like IbPy?

```
pip install IbPy2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Official Website of Tdameritrade, please install tdameritrade 0.0.4 with following code:

```
pip install tdameritrade
```

Comment: Where does it say anywhere that this is "official"?